# Avoiding duplicates when joining tables

Tags: sql, duplicates, presto, trino

By using the following two tables, I would like to pick up all the unique fruits which made more than 200 EUR in total and the number of times they were looked up by unique customers in a website.

**table_A (list of sold items)**

| fruit_id | fruit_name | price | purchased_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 100 | 2024-01-01 |
| 2 | Banana | 180 | 2024-01-01 |
| 1 | Apple | 50 | 2024-01-02 |
| 1 | Apple | 100 | 2024-01-02 |

*The same fruit could have different prices

**table_B (records of fruits being searched in a website)**

| fruit_id | fruit_name | web_customer_id | searched_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 123 | 2024-01-01 |
| 2 | Banana | 123 | 2024-01-01 |
| 1 | Apple | 123 | 2024-01-02 |
| 1 | Apple | 456 | 2024-01-02 |
| 1 | Apple | 789 | 2024-01-01 |
| 2 | Banana | 123 | 2024-01-01 |
| 1 | Apple | 123 | 2024-01-02 |
| 1 | Apple | 456 | 2024-01-02 |

In this example, the expected result should look like below:

| fruit_id | fruit_name | sum_sale | array_price | number_searched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 250 | 100, 50, 100 | 3 |

Banana should not be picked up because the sum of the sale is not more than 200 EUR.

If I simply join two tables like below, it creates a lot of duplicates.

```
select
a.fruit_id
,array_agg(distinct a.fruit_name) as fruit_name
,sum(a.price) as sum_sale
,array_agg(a.price) as array_price
,count(distinct b.web_customer_id) as number_searched

from table_A a
left join table_B b on a.fruit_id = b.fruit_id

GROUP BY a.fruit_id

having sum(a.price) > 200
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Add `GROUP BY a.fruit_id` before the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add that in the example. It still creates duplicates for the two output columns for price though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform grouping and filtering before joining:

```sql
-- sample data
with table_A (fruit_id, fruit_name, price, purchased_time) as(
    values (1,  'Apple',    100,    '2024-01-01'),
        (2, 'Banana',   180,    '2024-01-01'),
        (1, 'Apple',    50, '2024-01-02'),
        (1, 'Apple',    100,    '2024-01-02')),
table_B (fruit_id, fruit_name, web_customer_id, searched_time) as (
    values (1,  'Apple',    123,    '2024-01-01'),
    (2, 'Banana',   123,    '2024-01-01'),
    (1, 'Apple',    123,    '2024-01-02'),
    (1, 'Apple',    456,    '2024-01-02'),
    (1, 'Apple',    789,    '2024-01-01'),
    (2, 'Banana',   123,    '2024-01-01'),
    (1, 'Apple',    123,    '2024-01-02'),
    (1, 'Apple',    456,    '2024-01-02')),

-- query parts
grouped_a as (
    select a.fruit_id
     , array_agg(distinct a.fruit_name) fruit_name
     , sum(a.price) sum_sale
     , array_agg(a.price) array_price
    from table_A a
    GROUP BY a.fruit_id
    having sum(a.price) > 200),
grouped_b as (
    select fruit_id
        , count(distinct b.web_customer_id) number_searched
    from table_B b
    group by fruit_id)

select a.*, b.number_searched
from grouped_a a
join grouped_b b on a.fruit_id = b.fruit_id;
```

Output:

```
 fruit_id | fruit_name | sum_sale |  array_price   | number_searched 
----------+------------+----------+----------------+-----------------
        1 | [Apple]    |      250 | [100, 50, 100] |               3
```